# How do I get this script to multiply a number that was typed into the input field?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm trying to pull the number that a user types into a  text field and multiply that by a number that is already established. (There are other buttons that add +1 or subtract -1 from the total that work just fine. The only problem I'm having is this right here, getting a user's input by them typing in a value to a field and pulling it)

Here's my code:

```
<!-- HTML Field that I am trying to pull a number out of -->
<input type="text" id="multNumInput">
```

--

```
// Creative my variables
var number = 0;

// Creative a variable that is equal to whatever is inputted into the text box
var multNum = $("#multNumInput").val();

// On Button Click, take the number variable and multiply it times whatever the value was inputted in the html
$('#multiply').click(function(){
  number = number * multNum;
  $('result1').text(number);
  console.log(number);
})
```

Hopefully this is clear enough to understand. As of right now, whenever I click the button, it always changes the number back to 0. That's it. Just 0. No matter what I set the num var to, when clicking the mult button, it always reverts to 0.

Comment: You're failing to convert `multNum` from a string to a number - but more seriously, 0 times anything is still 0.

Comment: Yes of course 0 * 0 is 0 aha! As stated above, no matter what number it was being multiplied by, it was always equal to 0. I'll try converting it to a number, that seems like a simple fix. Thank you.

Comment: You also need to read the input value *inside* the click handler, rather than outside, so it always has an up to date value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to convert to number first.

```
multNum = parseInt(multNum);
number = number * multNum;
//...
```

Comment: Makes no difference with multiplication.... `console.log("2"*"2")`

Comment: Yes but to avoid any caveat it's always a good idea to convert to proper type first. Just because you can doesn't mean you should :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the *obvious*: Multiplying any number with your `number` variable which has `0` value will lead to 0 at all times - I suppose you know this but was confused or missed that part, probably by confusing it to initialization of `0` before an addition process. Set it to 1 or another non-negative number and you will probably get better results on the way. :)

In addition, to make it multiply correctly in JS, you have to multiply between two numbers.
Your value is of type `String` as inserted in your `input` field.
As already suggested by @Si8, you need to parse it to `Number` by doing:

```
multNum = parseInt(multNum);
```

Also, you seem to be using a text type for your input.
I suggest you set it to a `number` type, so that you restrict input values:

```
<input type="number" id="multNumInput">
```

Check out the Mozilla [MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number) for more on this.

Answer (score -2):

The answer, as provided by @Robin Zigmond in a comment is this:

***"You're failing to convert multNum from a string to a number."***

Comment: How is this an answer is beyond me... :-/